# uiautomatorviewer not running on Mac Big Sur

Tags: android, uiautomation, android-automation

I'm trying to run `uiautomatorviewer` on Big Sur and I'm getting this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runSettings(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
    at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:78)
```

Comment: Can you please share the code that is throwing that error?

Comment: I'm running [`uiautomatorviewer `](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-automator)  so that it launches the GUI so that I can inspect the UI of an Android emulator.

Comment: @Noldy, were you able to resolve this? I found others having issues with tools using SWT on BigSur. Seems like could be 32bit support related: https://forum.portfolio-performance.info/t/java-lang-nullpointerexception-on-mac-os-big-sur/9884/11..

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/47458/unable-to-launch-uiautomatorviewer-in-mac-os-big-sur) appears to be the same issue that you were seeing.
I followed [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/47458), which was to download the latest `SWT Binary and Source` release from the Eclipse Project, extract it, rename swt.jar to swt2.jar, and copy it to `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/swt2.jar`.

This workaround was originally suggested in [this issue report](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911).  One person said they also had to copy it to `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86/swt2.jar`, but I did need to do that.

In my case, I downloaded the [4.19 Mac OSX (64 bit version) release](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.19-202103031800/download.php?dropFile=swt-4.19-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip) for my (non-ARM) MacBook Pro.  You can find other releases on the [Eclipse Project Downloads page](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html).