# Unable to launch uiautomatorviewer in mac os Big Sur

Tags: android, mobile-automation

I recently updated my Mac OS to Big Sur. After that uiautomatorviewer is not working.

Before Big Sur, uiautomatorviewer use to work.

I am getting the below error:

/Users/xxxx/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin/uiautomatorviewer ; exit;

java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashFormLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillData.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeChildSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData.computeSize(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout.layout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.updateLayout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.layout(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runSettings(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)

at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)

at com.android.uiautomator.UiAutomatorViewer.main(UiAutomatorViewer.java:78)

---

/usr/libexec/java_home -V

Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):

1.8.291.10 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java" /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

1.8.0_291 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home

---

Java version:
java version "1.8.0_291"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)

---

which java

/usr/bin/java

---

echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home

---

echo $ANDROID_HOME

/Users/totjyoth/Library/Android/sdk

---

Bash profile:

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home

export ANDROID_HOME=~/Library/Android/sdk

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64

---

appium -v

1.20.2

---

Android Studio

Version 4.2

---

I am using Eclipse IDE

Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.

Version: 2019-12 (4.14.0)

Build id: 20191212-1212

---

I tried 'monitor', but that also gave an error:

xxxxx$ monitor
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_291.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/46388/uiautomatorviewer-not-running-on-mac-big-sur

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution here: https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/911#issuecomment-849389068.

Basically, you download the newest swt.jar from Eclipse site and use it (under a different name, e.g. `swt2.jar`) when starting `uiautomatorviewer`, something like:

```
java -Xmx1600M -XstartOnFirstThread -Dcom.android.uiautomator.bindir="$ANDROID_HOME/tools" -Djava.ext.dirs=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib -cp "$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/x86_64/swt.jar":"$ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/*" -jar $ANDROID_HOME/tools/lib/uiautomatorviewer-26.0.0-dev.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I copied swt.jar into `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64/swt2.jar` and it worked right away for me. (No need for modifying the `uiautomatorviewer` launch command.)

Comment: Also, in case it helps anyone, I downloaded the [4.19 Mac OSX (64 bit version) release of the SWT Binary and Source](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.19-202103031800/download.php?dropFile=swt-4.19-cocoa-macosx-x86_64.zip) for my (non-ARM) MacBook Pro.


You can find other releases on the [Eclipse Project Downloads page](https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/index.html).

Comment: I did all of the above but I am seeing the below error

```-Djava.ext.dirs=/Users/XXXXX/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/x86_64:/Users/XXXX/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.```

Comment: This seems to work only with Java 1.8, Java 11 or later results in this "Use -classpath instead." message